# Position popup menu in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, popupmenu

I have my button (btnLogout) in the right top corner in my app. When I press it I want the popupmenu to show from the top right corner. Now it popup in the middle of the screen. I have find similar questions, but I am not able to use gravity the right way.

Here is my code:

````
 btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button,Gravity.LEFT);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());


                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {



                        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                        if (id == R.id.loggout) {
                            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Innlogg.class);
                            startActivity(myintent);
                            return false;
                        }

                        if (id == R.id.privacy) {
                            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.bi.edu/about-bi/privacy-policy-and-cookies"));
                            startActivity(myWebLink);

                        }

                            return true;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        }); ```
````

Comment: I solved it by changing this line to this:
Old line: PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button,Gravity.LEFT);
New line: PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);

Answer (score 1):

```
//allows you to set PopupMenu to the specified coordinates
private void show(Activity pActivity, float x, float y)
        {
             final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) 
             pActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
             final View view = new View(context);
             view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(1, 1));
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
             root.addView(view);
             view.setX(x);
             view.setY(y);
             PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(context, view, Gravity.CENTER);
             menu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener()
                 {
                      @Override
                      public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu)
                      {
                            root.removeView(view);
                       }
                 });
            menu.show();
        }
```